# React Native Listener on Animated API value or use a SetInterval

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I am in a situation where I got 20,30 moving objects(views) on the screen and I need to track their xy location at every point in time.
I got 2 options

1. use react native animated API to move those objects and add a listener on that variable to track the values.

```
  const animatedValue = new Animated.ValueXY(0, 0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = animatedValue.addListener((value) => {
      // Do my stuff
    });

    return () => {
      animatedValue.removeListener(listener);
    };
  }, []);
```

2. avoid using animated API and simply use a normal variable with setInterval.

```
const position = useRef({ x: 0, y: 0 }).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      position.x += 1; // Increment x value
      position.y += 2; // Increment y value

      console.log('Current position:', position);

     
      if (position.x >= 200 && position.y >= 300) {
        // Do My Stuff
      }
    }, 16); // Run the interval every 16ms (60 frames per second)

    // Clean up the interval when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  
};
```

Even thought the formal one relaxes the JavaScript thread, I got a feeling that using a listener would do more damage than using setIntervals.

Any suggestions?